# Close dropdown with button - Angular Material

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using the selectTo dropdown in angular material design.

This is my code:

```
<mat-form-field id="inputClick" appearance="outline" (click)="Valid()">
<mat-label>{{'GENERAL.TITLE' | translate}} *</mat-label>
<mat-select  [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
    <div class="drpInput">
        <mat-form-field class="mat-form-field-fluid" appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>{{'GENERAL.TITLE' | translate}} *</mat-label>
            <input autocomplete="off" matInput [placeholder]="'GENERAL.TITLE' | translate"
                (keyup)="onTextChange($event.target.value)">
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div class="oprionSelect">
            <mat-option  (click)="selectedUser(item.id)" *ngFor="let item of users" [value]="item.id">
                    <label>{{ item.displayName | translate }} </label><span class="mar">({{item.userName}})</span>
                </mat-option>
    </div>
    <mat-progress-bar *ngIf="loading" mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-bar>
    <div class="row justofy-content-center text-center m-auto col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 col-lg12">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 col-lg-4 right">
            <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="next()" *ngIf="nextBtn">بعدی</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 col-lg-4" *ngIf="count!=0">
            <button mat-button (click)="close()" color="warn">انتخاب</button>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 col-lg-4 left">
            <button mat-button color="accent" (click)="prev()" *ngIf="prevBtn">قبلی</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</mat-select>
```

Upon clicking the 'finish' button, I want the dropdown to close. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MatSelect` has both `open` and `close` methods which you can use. There are few approaches that you can apply.

```
<mat-select #matSelect [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
   ....
   <button (click)="finish(matSelect)">Close</button>
</mat-select>
```

Or if you don't want to pass `matSelect` directly to `finish()` method, you can reference it to `ViewChild`

```
@ViewChild('matSelect') matSelect;

finish() {
   this.matSelect.close();
}
```

You can also close it directly from HTML:

```
<mat-select #matSelect [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
   ....
   <button (click)="matSelect.close()">Close</button>
</mat-select>
```

[**Stackblitz Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ufkjtq?file=src/app/select-overview-example.html)

For more details, take a look at the API documentation - [Select | Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api)